# "Unsupported ABI" error in chromium webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, chromium, android-source

I compiled, installed and run successfully my custom webview, based on chromium 46 (tag 46.0.2490.71) by following these instructions :

https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/android-build-instructions

and built the ninja target "system_webview_apk".

And it works great !

Now I am trying to integrate it in my custom android image based on lolipop 5.1.1_r29 built from AOSP. 
The build and install steps work, but when an application tries to inflate the webview, I have the following error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ABI: null
 at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.getInstructionSet(VMRuntime.java:324)
 at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.is64BitAbi(VMRuntime.java:337)
 at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewNativeLibraryPaths(WebViewFactory.java:286)
```

(Full stack trace at the end of the post)

The strange thing is that, if I take the **exact** same APK, and install it with ADB :

```
adb shell stop
adb pull /system/app/webview/webview.apk
adb shell rm -rf /system/app/webview/
adb shell start
adb install webview.apk
```

Then the error disapears and the webview shows up correctly.

Next, if I put it back again in /system/app :

```
adb uninstall com.android.webview
adb push webview.apk /system/app/webview/webview.apk
adb shell stop
adb shell start
```

It fails again with the same error.

My investigation about the "Unsupported ABI: null" only gave me this :
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=559720

But it doesn’t seem related.

I need the webview based on chromium 46 (at least) on android 5.1.1.

Any help, clue or suggestion will be appreciated :)

### Some additional piece of information :

On the nexus 6 :

```
root@shamu:/ # ll /system/lib/libwebv*
-rw-r--r-- root     root     31282132 2008-04-15 23:40 libwebviewchromium.so
-rw-r--r-- root     root         5376 2015-12-09 15:51 libwebviewchromium_loader.so
-rw-r--r-- root     root         9532 2015-12-09 15:51 libwebviewchromium_plat_support.so
```

Chromium build configuration :

```
$ cat chromium.gyp_env
{ 'GYP_DEFINES': 'target_arch=arm OS=android', }

$ cat .gclient
solutions = [
  { "name"        : "src",
    "url"         : "https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git",
    "deps_file"   : "DEPS",
    "managed"     : False,
    "custom_deps" : {
    },
    "safesync_url": "",
  },
]
cache_dir = None
target_os = ["android"]
```

Full stack trace :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.webviewui/com.example.webviewui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
     at com.example.webviewui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
     at com.example.webviewui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ABI: null
     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.getInstructionSet(VMRuntime.java:324)
     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.is64BitAbi(VMRuntime.java:337)
     at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewNativeLibraryPaths(WebViewFactory.java:286)
     at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.loadNativeLibrary(WebViewFactory.java:397)
     at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:103)
     at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2194)
     at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2189)
     at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2248)
     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3588)
     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3682)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
     at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:544)
     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:489)
     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:472)
     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:459)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
     at com.example.webviewui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: if you perform "adb shell pm dump com.google.android.webview" you'll notice that the primary and secondary CpuAbi fields are set correctly.
Another oddity, is that installing as a system app doesn't seem to create the lib directory that is supposed to contain the native libraries. I don't know *why* these behaviours are different, but this is what some of my initial investigation is showing up.

Comment: When I tried to do `adb uninstall com.android.webview`, it gave me the error `Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]`. Did you observe this ?

Comment: @eurythmia system apps don't use private lib directories, unlike 'normal' apps. The native libraries for system apps are copied to **/system/lib** (or **/system/lib64**) when AOSP image is built. See also https://android.stackexchange.com/a/190626/22992

Answer (score 2):

When compiling the WebView for arm, Chromium (64.0.3282.134, and likely other versions) will target armv7. This results in putting native libraries under the armeabi-v7a folder in the apk. When this is installed on my example armv7 Android 5.1.1 device Android will run dex2opt to process the apk. In doing so it will look for native libraries under the armeabi folder, not the armeabi-v7a folder. Because of this, it will never find the libraries and when the WebView is launched it fails.

Chromium's source has comments saying that it no longer supports armeabi, so building for that appears to not be viable. I did attempt to explicitly build for arm version 6 and hit compile failures.

The workaround I've found is this:

1. Unzip the built Chromium webview apk
2. Rename the library folder from `armeabi-v7a` to `armeabi`
3. Zip everything back up, renaming the resulting file as an apk. (Note, when zipping do not compress the contents. The WebView expects some of its assets to not be compressed, and compressing them results in a runtime failure).
4. Use `zipalign` and `apksigner` to get the apk ready to install
5. Install the resulting apk file

Doing so I observed the Android 5.1.1 device was able to find the native libraries and use them when launching the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install a system app by simply pushing the APK to **/system/app/**. And it's not enough to have its native libraries copied to **/system/lib/**. You also must create the relevant entry in the **/data/system/packages.xml** file, with **primaryCpuAbi** set to **arm**.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to a mismatch between 32/64-bit devices. There's a bug open in chromium.org here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=559720#c2

> "Unsupported ABI: null" can mean a 32/64-bit mismatch. We've been seeing an issue when vendors issue OTAs which upgrade 64-bit devices from 32- to 64-bit Android. There's a bug in PlayStore where such devices will continue to get the 32-bit WebView. That may be what's happening here. We have an internal bug open for this but I can't say when it'll get fixed. :( Users can get to the right version by uninstalling WebView updates in Settings and then re-updating WebView in the Play Store.

Quoting another comment from the above source:

> This issue should sort itself out after the next time the user runs the play store app for any reason (the issue only occurs during automatic updates and running the play store fixes the incorrect state that makes it install the wrong package).

Originally answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61499257/4997507